# PokerGame deciding cards

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing a program where 2 random numbers are generated which are assigned to two rows. This row is a hand that is being dealt to a player which is to be converted from number to actually card value 
    `Ex. row 1290 contains [1,2,4,5,3,7,2,12,3,1,0] that has [2 of hearts, 5 of clubs, 7 of diamonds, queen of spades, ace of diamonds]`

How can I make my code

```
import random
#opening the poker file and generating the random numbers
poker_file = open("poker-hand-testing.data",'r')
number_one = random.randint(0,1000000)
number_two = random.randint(0,1000000)
row_int = 0
#loop to check if both random numbers generated are different
while number_one == number_two:
    number_two = random.randint(0,1000000)
#Establishing the hand drawn by both players
for line_str in poker_file:
    row_int = row_int + 1
    row_str = line_str.split(',')
    if row_int == number_one:
        hand1 = row_str
    elif row_int == number_two:
        hand2 = row_str
for i in [0,2,6,8]:
    suit_int = int(hand1[i])
    if suit_int == 1:
        suit1 = "Hearts"
    elif suit_int == 2:
        suit2 = "Spades"
    elif suit_int == 3:
        suit3 ="Diamonds"
    elif suit_int == 4:
        suit4 = "Clubs"
for p in [1,3,5,7]:
    value_int = int(hand1[p])
    if value_int == 1:
        value_one = "Ace"
    elif 1 < value_int < 11:
        value2 = str(value_int)
    elif value_int == 11:
        value3 ="Jack"
    elif value_int == 12:
        value4 = "Queen"
    elif value_int == 13:
        value5 = "King"
```

print exactly how the row is listed.

Comment: Ick why are you doing it like this? You're asking for trouble. Just make a `class Card` that has all that information in it and have a list of Card objects

Comment: So `poker_file` is a text file of these "hands?" Each hand is on its own line, yes? Doesn't that mean `hand1[0]` is a `"["`?

Comment: @AdamSmith the text file doesn't contain `"["` beause it is just the row of numbers but when I call the file it makes it into a list so`hand1[0]` is `1` not `[`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from enum import Enum, IntEnum

hand1 = [1,2,4,5,3,7,2,12,3,1,0]
hand2 = [2,3,3,3,4,3,1,3,4,1,0]

class Suits(Enum):
    Hearts = 1
    Spades = 2
    Diamonds = 3
    Clubs = 4
class Ranks(IntEnum):
    Ace = 1    # writing this was the first time I thought to myself
    Two = 2    # "...gee, I wish I were writing in golang right now"
    Three = 3  # iotas are wonderful.
    Four = 4
    Five = 5
    Six = 6
    Seven = 7
    Eight = 8
    Nine = 9
    Ten = 10
    Jack = 11
    Queen = 12
    King = 13

class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, suit, rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    @classmethod
    def from_tuple(cls, tup):
        suit, rank = tup
        return cls(Suits(suit), Ranks(rank))

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0.rank.name} of {0.suit.name}".format(self)

    # This is allllll framework stuff so that it's easier to handle these later!

import itertools

def grouper(iterator, n):
    """From itertools recipes"""
    args = [iter(iterator)] * n
    return itertools.zip_longest(fillvalue=0, *args)

hand = [Card.from_tuple(group) for group in grouper(hand1, 2)
        if 0 not in group]
other_hand = [Card.from_tuple(group) for group in grouper(hand2, 2)
              if 0 not in group]
```

Like with most programming, the difficult part is building the framework. The easy part is working with it afterwards. Build something useful and reap the benefits later!

And in Golang, just because I'm practicing

```go
package main

import "fmt"

type Card struct {
    suit int
    rank int
}

func (c *Card) String() string {
    suit_mapping := map[int]string{
        1: "Hearts",
        2: "Spades",
        3: "Diamonds",
        4: "Clubs"}
    rank_mapping := map[int]string{
        1:  "Ace",  // I lied! iota only works on consts!
        2:  "Two",
        3:  "Three",
        4:  "Four",
        5:  "Five",
        6:  "Six",
        7:  "Seven",
        8:  "Eight",
        9:  "Nine",
        10: "Ten",
        11: "Jack",
        12: "Queen",
        13: "King",
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s of %s", rank_mapping[c.rank], suit_mapping[c.suit])
}

func main() {
    hand1_values := []int{1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 7, 2, 12, 3, 1, 0}
    hand1 := make([]Card, 0)

    for idx, val := range hand1_values {
        var suit int
        var rank int
        if val == 0 {
            break // last value!
        }
        if idx%2 == 0 {
            // suit
            suit = val
            rank = hand1_values[idx+1]
        } else {
            continue
        }
        c := Card{suit: suit, rank: rank}
        hand1 = append(hand1, c)
    }

    for _, c := range hand1 {
        fmt.Println(c.String())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following ideas might help. Rather than build a list of numbers for the hand, you could work directly with enumerated values.

First create a whole pack of cards based on the product of `Suits` and `Numbers`. Shuffle this and remove two hands from the pack, optionally sort the two hands and display the two hands side by side, followed by the remaining cards in the pack:

```
from enum import IntEnum
import random
from itertools import product

hand_size = 5
Suits = IntEnum('Suit', 'Hearts Spades Diamonds Clubs')
Numbers = IntEnum('Number', 'Ace Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight Nine Ten Jack Queen King')

# Create a complete pack of cards and shuffle it
pack = [(s, n) for s, n in product(Suits, Numbers)]
random.shuffle(pack)

hand_1 = sorted(pack[:hand_size])
del(pack[:hand_size])

hand_2 = sorted(pack[:hand_size])
del(pack[:hand_size])

print '{:45} {}'.format('Hand 1', 'Hand 2')
for card_1, card_2 in zip(hand_1, hand_2):
    print '{:45} {}'.format(card_1, card_2)

print
print 'Remaining cards in pack'
for card in pack:
    print card
```

Giving you the following kind of output:

```
Hand 1                                        Hand 2
(<Suit.Hearts: 1>, <Number.Seven: 7>)         (<Suit.Hearts: 1>, <Number.Ace: 1>)
(<Suit.Spades: 2>, <Number.Seven: 7>)         (<Suit.Spades: 2>, <Number.Four: 4>)
(<Suit.Spades: 2>, <Number.King: 13>)         (<Suit.Diamonds: 3>, <Number.Ace: 1>)
(<Suit.Clubs: 4>, <Number.Ace: 1>)            (<Suit.Diamonds: 3>, <Number.Seven: 7>)
(<Suit.Clubs: 4>, <Number.Three: 3>)          (<Suit.Clubs: 4>, <Number.Two: 2>)

Remaining cards in pack
(<Suit.Diamonds: 3>, <Number.Three: 3>)
(<Suit.Diamonds: 3>, <Number.Five: 5>)
(<Suit.Diamonds: 3>, <Number.Queen: 12>)
(<Suit.Clubs: 4>, <Number.Jack: 11>)
.
.
.
etc
```